# ListView ItemTemplate 100% width

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps

How can I make content of each `ListView` item expands to 100% width when using a `DataTemplate`?

I have tried `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"` in the `ListView` and `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` in the `DataTemplate`, but nothing seems to work, content is still aligned to the left.

I have something like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="questionsView" Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Background="BlueViolet" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right">16 minutes ago</TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I guess there is one more layer between the `ListView` and the `ItemTemplate`.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

I got it. Setting the `ListView.ItemContainerStyle` with a `HorizontalContentAlignment` setter makes the trick. I.e.:

```
<ListView x:Name="questionsView" Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Background="BlueViolet">
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right">16 minutes ago</TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

Comment: What control are you using as DataTemplate? Grid? My trick is, I always use color backgrounds to see which is the control that is not expanding.

Comment: If the text of the first `TextBlock` is too long it'll cover the `TextBlock` on the right. You should create two `Grid.ColumnDefinitions` and put each textblock in its own column to avoid this.

Comment: This solution worked for me, even though I use Groups with `ListView.GroupStyle` and [CollectionViewSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.aspx)

Comment: I tested it on UWP Windows for IoT and it works perfectly. Thank you :)

Answer (score 9):

Set the item container's property of **HorizontalContentAlignment** to Stretch, try this

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
   <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
       <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
   </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: You are wrong. Should be HorizontalContentAlignment instead of VerticalContentAlignment

Answer (score 7):

What is important here is the `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility`, `TextWrapping` and `ItemContainerStyle` with `HorizontalContentAlignment`. The rest is fluff.

```
<ListView VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Prop1}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

</ListView>
```