# Windows 8.1, XAML binding listview but not showing the first item

Tags: c#, windows, xaml

Below is my code

```
    <ListView ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" SelectionMode="None" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" CanReorderItems="False" CanDragItems="False" IsRightTapEnabled="False" IsItemClickEnabled="True" BorderBrush="White" Background="White" ItemClick="lvGroupInfoCVS_ItemClick"  RequestedTheme="Light" FontFamily="Helvetica" x:Name="lvGroupInfoCVS" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyCollection}}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Width="{Binding ElementName=lvGroupInfoCVS, Path=ActualWidth}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition  Width="1*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" FontFamily="Helvetica" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="DarkGray" FontSize="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"  FontFamily="Helvetica" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding EventDate}" Foreground="DarkGray" FontSize="23" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" FontFamily="Helvetica" Grid.Row="0"  Text="{Binding StartTime}" Foreground="DarkGray" FontSize="23" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

All my data shows up properly but my first item is blank, although it is clickable. I tried changing the width and height but I still have the same issue

Environment: Windows 8.1, XAML, C#

I tried looking into the other similar stackoverflow questions but had no luck

Comment: possible duplicate of [ListView ItemTemplate 100% width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18626696/listview-itemtemplate-100-width)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I just fixed it!
Both of us tried to set `Grid Width` by binding to `ListView.ActualWidth`, but it's not working until first element will be rendered, so first elemnt always have 0 Width :(

To solve this, please do this (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18626907/3702797) by [@Kievic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/27211/kiewic)

> Setting the ListView.ItemContainerStyle with a
>   HorizontalContentAlignment setter makes the trick.

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Even if your link does contain an answer to this question, please paste relevant parts into your answer.

Comment: A link to another SO answer is not a good answer.  This should be a suggested duplicate for the question.

Comment: I just ran into the same issue, and this answer was extremely helpful. I might never have guessed that the ActualWidth binding was yielding zero for the first item. Thanks so much!

Comment: This not works for me. I solved settings a `MinWidth` to the first control of the `DataTemplate`

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
<ListView SelectedIndex="0">
```

If you want it to select the first item in the list on load.