# Windows 8 list view first item not displaying when bound the first time

Tags: c#, listview, windows-8.1

I am binding to a `listview` but when I bind for the first time, the first item is not displayed. It is there in the list and if I click on where I know it should be (at the top) I can use that data so the only issue is with displaying it. Please note the issue is only on the first time the list is bound.

As you can see from the code below I bind to the `listview` on the third character being entered, this is when I get the problem. Once the forth is entered all matching result are displayed and if I delete the third character (so nothing is bound), then re-enter the a character the list shows all matching results.

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtSupName" SelectionChanged="txtSupName_SelectionChanged" Style="{StaticResource DefaultTextbox}"/>

<ListView x:Name="lvFilteredSuppliers" Margin="0,50,0,0" Height="200" SelectionChanged="lvFilteredSuppliers_SelectionChanged">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Width="{Binding ElementName=lvFilteredSuppliers, Path=ActualWidth}">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="410" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding SupplierName}" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding SupplierCode}" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding SupplierTown}" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding SupplierCountry}" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>


    private void txtSupName_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //only start checking when there are more than 2 charaters entered
        if (txtSupName.Text.Length > 2)
        {
            //select all suppliers that match with user input
            var filteredSuppliers = Suppliers.Where(l => l.SupplierName.ToLower().StartsWith(txtSupName.Text.ToLower()));

            //filteredSuppliers passed to observable collection so listView will update on each change
            ObservableCollection<SupplierLocal> filteredSuppliersCollection = new ObservableCollection<SupplierLocal>(filteredSuppliers);

            //sets the source for the listview
            lvFilteredSuppliers.ItemsSource = filteredSuppliersCollection;

            //shows grid
            gridListViewContainer.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            //hides grid
            gridListViewContainer.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
```

The only post I could find that was similar to this problem was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20976172/windows-8-1-xaml-binding-listview-but-not-showing-the-first-item) but the accepted answer did not work for me.

Why is my issue happening and how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

May be it necropost. But still, I leave it here.

I had the same problem on WinRT apps.
I as well as you used to bind to the width of the parent container. Then I delete this binding and first item was shown.
Try to delete this from your grid inside the DataTemplate:

```
Width="{Binding ElementName=lvFilteredSuppliers, Path=ActualWidth}"
```