# Align radio button to right side of popup

Tags: win-universal-app

I have a popup for select colors.

```
<Popup x:Name="colorSelectorPopup">
    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gray">
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Grid x:Name="colorSelectorTitle" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="popupTitle" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="8"/>
                </Grid>
                <ListView x:Name="colorList" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="White">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" x:Name="tbColor" Text="{Binding ColorName}" Foreground="{Binding ForegroundColor}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                                <RadioButton Grid.Column="1" x:Name="radioColor" GroupName="colorRadio" Tag="{Binding SelectionColor}" MinWidth="32" Checked="radioColor_Checked"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</Popup>
```

I want the radio button to show on the right side. But It looks as in the image.

How can I move the radio button to the right side?

[image]

Comment: Just add HorizontalAlignment=Right ??

Comment: @Pedro G Dias    I tried it but didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18626907/799141).

By Adding the following xaml I got the desired output.

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

This works for me. I have updated my xaml as follows

```
<Popup x:Name="colorSelectorPopup">
    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gray">
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Grid x:Name="colorSelectorTitle" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="popupTitle" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="8"/>
                </Grid>
                <ListView x:Name="colorList" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="White">
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                                </Style>
                    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" x:Name="tbColor" Text="{Binding ColorName}" Foreground="{Binding ForegroundColor}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                                <RadioButton Grid.Column="1" x:Name="radioColor" GroupName="colorRadio" Tag="{Binding SelectionColor}" MinWidth="32" Checked="radioColor_Checked"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</Popup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the grid only contains 2 columns and the 2nd column only contains the radio button I would set the column definition to a fixed with for the 2nd one instead of auto. see if that works.

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```